# Error In Executing A Batch File From A Java Program

Tags: java, perl, process, batch-file, processbuilder

Here is my problem:
I have a .bat file which has a number of commands. When I invoke this bat file from my java program using processbuilder it starts executing the commands in .bat file line by line. However when it reaches the last line which executes a perl program it hangs and the program never ends. It hangs there forever. Any idea why this might be happening. Just for your information there is no problem with the perl code and I'm able to execute

Comment: Can you run the perl from java, with or without a `.bat` script?

Comment: my guess is that the PATH environment var is not set so the perl interpreter is not found. Try supplying the fullpath for tjhe perl interpreter aka: c:\the\path\to\perl\perl.exe ...

Comment: I think we'd need to see the batch file and the Perl script to be of any help.  See if you can duplicate the buggy behavior in a small example that you can post here.

Comment: `it hangs there forever` how do you know ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I was able to fix this problem. All I had to do was to include a statement in my java code which closes the output stream of the process. Without which it was waiting on the command line for the perl program to be executed forever. I'm not exactly sure about the behavior, any information would be help

Answer (score 2):

Does your perl program write to standard output?
I suspect the problem is that a Java process redirects the child process' standard output and standard error output to a pipe.
The receiving end of that pipe is connected to the java program, so any child process invoked from java that writes to standard output / error will block if you fail to read its output. 
You must either eliminate the perl program's output or read the child process' output (`Process.getInputStream()` and/or `Process.getErrorStream()`) from within your java program.

Comment: : Hey I was able to fix this problem. All I had to do was to include a statement in my java code which closes the output stream of the process. Without which it was waiting on the command line for the perl program to be executed forever. I'm not exactly sure about the behavior, any information would be help.